# Azure alert report showing a Resource not found message

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights, azure-alerts

We have created an alert in Azure AppInsights as many times before, in this particular alert, when we receive the message and click the "View x results" button to see the results of the query that generated the alert we see an empty browser with:

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

[image]

The email received is the normal one, nothing special.

[image]

This works on the rest of the alerts, we already recreated the alert and keeps failing.

Comment: As per the error message, you can first check if the resources are deleted / available or not.

Comment: What resources should we check for? This is a working query that triggers an alert. The application is there, the alert is there (in fact the alert was triggered correctly). What resources Azure builds when an alert is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a issue support will be able to help with. Sometimes the resource is not synced with the ARM and it can cause such issues.